# FTPES - FTP over explicit TLS/SSL in Python

Tags: python, ftp, tcp, ftpes

I need a python client to do FTPES (explicit), does anyone has experience with any python package that can do this.

I am not able to do this in python, but can connect to FTP server using tools like FileZilla

Thanks

Answer (score 33):

FTP-SSL Explicit is well supported by native Python. After setting up the connection, you can use all the standard ftplib commands. More can be found at:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS

Here's a basic example for downloading a file:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS('ftp.MySite.com')
# login after securing control channel
ftps.login('testuser', 'testpass')           
# switch to secure data connection.. 
# IMPORTANT! Otherwise, only the user and password is encrypted and
# not all the file data.
ftps.prot_p()          
ftps.retrlines('LIST')

filename = 'remote_filename.bin'
print 'Opening local file ' + filename
with open(filename, 'wb') as myfile:
    ftps.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, myfile.write)

ftps.close()
```

Comment: However, for servers requiring reuse of TLS session in data channels, there is a need to subclass FTP_TLS, see workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43301750.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was receiving `ftplib.error_perm: 534 Policy requires SSL` the whole day, solved by using the `.prot_p()` to switch to secure data connection.

Answer (score 15):

For me this worked: (login after auth). Taken from [Nullege](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40y%40pypy-HEAD%40lib-python%402.7%40test%40test_ftplib.py/598/ftplib.FTP_TLS/python). They seem to be tests for [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html).

```
self.client = ftplib.FTP_TLS(timeout=10)
self.client.connect(self.server.host, self.server.port)

# enable TLS
self.client.auth()
self.client.prot_p()

self.client.login(user,pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard ftplib does contain everything you need for ftpes (ftps explicit) connection. I didn't find easy way to make implicit connections.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS

Answer (score 0):

> I need a python client to do FTPES (explicit), does anyone has experience with any python package that can do this.

`ftplib` in `stdlib` should do what you want... an example, lifted from the docs...

```py
>>> from ftplib import FTP_TLS
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>>
>>> ftpes = FTP_TLS('ftp.cisco.com', timeout=5)
>>> passwd = getpass("Enter your password:")
Enter your password:
>>> ftpes.login("username", passwd)   # login before securing channel
>>> ftpes.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection
>>> ftpes.retrlines('LIST') # list directory content securely
total 9
drwxr-xr-x   8 root     wheel        1024 Jan  3  1994 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 root     wheel        1024 Jan  3  1994 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel        1024 Jan  3  1994 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel        1024 Jan  3  1994 etc
d-wxrwxr-x   2 ftp      wheel        1024 Sep  5 13:43 incoming
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel        1024 Nov 17  1993 lib
drwxr-xr-x   6 1094     wheel        1024 Sep 13 19:07 pub
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     wheel        1024 Jan  3  1994 usr
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root          312 Aug  1  1994 welcome.msg
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> filename = "welcome.msg"
>>> ftpes.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> ftpes.close()
>>>
```

Comment: can use via proxy?

Comment: This hangs for us with a timeout, though we're able to retrieve a listing using:
curl -ssl --list_only --user USER:PASS ftp://ftp.company.com:port/public

Any thoughts?