# FTPS with Python ftplib - Session reuse required

Tags: python, ftp, python-2.7, ftps, ftplib

So, I am trying to connect to an FTP server to get directory listings and download files. But the first command after the `prot_p()` function is raising an exception - Producing these errors from the log:

```
*get* '150 Here comes the directory listing.\r\n'
*resp* '150 Here comes the directory listing.'
*get* '522 SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse
option in vsftpd.conf man page\r\n'
*resp* '522 SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse
 option in vsftpd.conf man page'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\download.py", line 29, in <module>
    files = ftps.dir()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 522, in dir
    self.retrlines(cmd, func)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 725, in retrlines
    return self.voidresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 522 SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see requir
e_ssl_reuse option in vsftpd.conf man page
```

Here is the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os
import socket

host = 'example.com'
port = 34567
user = 'user1'
passwd = 'pass123'
acct = 'Normal'

ftps = FTP_TLS()

ftps.set_debuglevel(2)

ftps.connect(host, port)

print(ftps.getwelcome())
print(ftps.sock)

ftps.auth()

ftps.login(user, passwd, acct)

ftps.set_pasv(True)
ftps.prot_p()

print('Current directory:')
print(ftps.pwd())
files = ftps.dir()

ftps.quit()
```

I want to do this securely, hence using FTP over TLS Explicit. I have the idea that I may need to manipulate some settings in the `Socket` class referenced by ftplib. Changing the settings on the server is not a possibility. I have tested the server successfully with FileZilla client, an older version of WinSCP was raising the same error - although an upgrade to the newest version fixed it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 44):

It can be now easily fixed for **Python 3.6+** by this class (descendant  of FTP_TLS):

```
class MyFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """Explicit FTPS, with shared TLS session"""
    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        conn, size = ftplib.FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
        if self._prot_p:
            conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
                                            server_hostname=self.host,
                                            session=self.sock.session)  # this is the fix
        return conn, size
```

It takes the TLS session information from the initial "control" FTP connection and reuses it also for every second "data" connection that is frequently created and closed for every new data transfer of a file body or a directory list. The reuse is advantageous for the server because it does not require a repeated TLS handshake many times. That is exactly what you did see in the message `session reuse required`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Just wonder when it will finally get past Review stage from Python bug issue :-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me hotpatch an FTP TLS upload - along with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057732/connecting-to-explicit-ftp-over-tls-in-python

Answer (score 9):

It looks more likely a **vsftpd** issue than **ftplib** as you mention an upgrade to the newest version fixed the problem.

Provided that you cannot touch server's settings, sub-classing the `FTP_TLS` may help resolve your issue, although it is quite a *HACK* in my opinion, referenced to this SO question & answers [Python FTP TLS connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164470/python-ftp-tls-connection-issue). You can also take a look from this [python bug issue 19500](http://bugs.python.org/issue19500):

> "  It is reasonable for the server to insist that the data connection 
>   uses a TLS cached session.  This might be a cache of a previous data
>   connection or of a cleared control connection.  If this is the reason 
>   for the refusal to allow the data transfer, then the '522' reply
>   should indicate this.
>
> Note: This has an important impact on client design, but allows
>   servers to minimize the cycles used during TLS negotiation by
>   refusing to perform a full negotiation with a previously
>   authenticated client."
>
> It appears that vsftpd server implemented exactly that by enforcing
>   the "SSL session reuse between the control and data connection".
>
> http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2009/02/vsftpd-210-released.html
>
> Looking at the source of Python core library ftplib.py, there isn't
>   any regard to the idea of SSL session reuse between data connection
>   vs. control connection (correct me if I am wrong here. I've tried
>   FTP_TLS.transfercmd(cmd[, rest])¶, didn't work).
>
> This issue is well documented on other FTP clients that supports FTPS,
>   I.E. WinSCP: https://winscp.net/tracker/668
>
> See test log file attached. A vsftpd server with "require_ssl_reuse"
>   set to true in vsftpd.conf would do the trick and can be reproduced.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never had control over the FTP server  configuration and have since lost access and am unable to test this solution.