# ftplib - 504 Security mechanism 'TLS' not implemented

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to connect to Secure FTP using `ftplib`, but it does not work for some reason (trying to connect to www.sharefile.com ftp. there it says to use this address: company.sharefileftp.com)

I'm trying this approach ([FTPES - FTP over explicit TLS/SSL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534830/ftpes-ftp-over-explicit-tls-ssl-in-python)):

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS('company.sharefileftp.com')
ftps.login('user', 'pass')           # login anonymously before securing control channel
ftps.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection.. IMPORTANT! Otherwise, only the user and password is encrypted and not all the file data.
ftps.retrlines('LIST')

filename = 'remote_filename.bin'
print 'Opening local file ' + filename
myfile = open(filename, 'wb')

ftps.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, myfile.write)

ftps.close()
```

But it gives me this error (when calling this line `ftps.login('testuser', 'testpass')`):

```
error_perm                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-bfe01179f1c2> in <module>()
----> ftps.login('user', 'pass')

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in login(self, user, passwd, acct, secure)
    650         def login(self, user='', passwd='', acct='', secure=True):
    651             if secure and not isinstance(self.sock, ssl.SSLSocket):
--> 652                 self.auth()
    653             return FTP.login(self, user, passwd, acct)
    654 

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in auth(self)
    658                 raise ValueError("Already using TLS")
    659             if self.ssl_version == ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1:
--> 660                 resp = self.voidcmd('AUTH TLS')
    661             else:
    662                 resp = self.voidcmd('AUTH SSL')

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in voidcmd(self, cmd)
    252         """Send a command and expect a response beginning with '2'."""
    253         self.putcmd(cmd)
--> 254         return self.voidresp()
    255 
    256     def sendport(self, host, port):

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in voidresp(self)
    227     def voidresp(self):
    228         """Expect a response beginning with '2'."""
--> 229         resp = self.getresp()
    230         if resp[:1] != '2':
    231             raise error_reply, resp

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in getresp(self)
    222             raise error_temp, resp
    223         if c == '5':
--> 224             raise error_perm, resp
    225         raise error_proto, resp
    226 

error_perm: 504 Security mechanism 'TLS' not implemented.
```

**P.S.** But I can connect using FTP (not secure one):

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('company.sharefileftp.com')     # connect to host, default port
>>> ftp.login('user', 'pass')                     # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting with the Explicit TLS/SSL (what is generally the recommended mode).

It seems that the sharefile.com does support Implicit TLS/SSL only (what is quite unusual).

Contrary, it seems that the ftplib does not support Implicit TLS/SSL out of the box.

You can fix it though. See answers to:
[Python FTP implicit TLS connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12164470/850848)

Answer (score 1):

The server simply does not support TLS, neither the old 'AUTH SSL' nor the newer 'AUTH TLS'. This problem is unrelated to python as the following test with telnet shows:

```
$telnet company.sharefileftp.com 21
Trying 54.194.108.219...
Connected to company.sharefileftp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ftp-eu-1.sharefileftp.com FTP Server Ready
AUTH TLS
504 Security mechanism 'TLS' not implemented.
AUTH SSL
504 Security mechanism 'SSL' not implemented.
QUIT
221-Sent: 142 bytes   Rcvd: 26 bytes   Time: 15s
221 ftp-eu-1.sharefileftp.com session ended.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But it does support the (old and never standardized) implicit TLS:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect company.sharefileftp.com:990
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
   Cipher    : RC4-SHA
...
220 ftp-eu-1.sharefileftp.com FTP Server Ready (SSL)
```